# TypeError: 'LogisticRegression' object is not callable in logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I have a problem when I tried to use logistic regression with the idea to determine a t predicted value in the penultimate line. The error is:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
line 15, in 
    t_pred = logreg(X_test)
TypeError: 'LogisticRegression' object is not callable"

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
df=pd.read_csv('datos.csv')
X=df1 = df.iloc[:,1:5]
t=df.iloc[:,0]
X_train, X_test, t_train, t_test = train_test_split(X, t, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
logreg=LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
predicted = cross_val_predict(logreg, X_train, t_train, cv=10)
print(accuracy_score(t_train, predicted))
logreg.fit(X_train, t_train)
t_pred = logreg(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(t_test, t_pred))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to:

```
t_pred = logreg(X_test)
```

You need to use a method of the object `logreg`, not supply the params directly to it.

Notice how you used `logreg.fit()`. `fit()` is a method which handles the training data. Similarly, you will need to call `predict()` to get the predictions on new data.

Try this:

```
t_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
```